# Open Office Base Datetime Default

Tags: database, database-design, datetime, default

Can anyone tell me how to set the default value on a date field in Open Office Base, in the same way that GetDate() works for SQL Server?

Cheers
OneSHOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give CURDATE() a try.

Found at http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Built-in_functions_and_Stored_Procedures

Comment: +1 for being the only answer :-) but I no longer have access to the setup to test this.  The project got canned and so did the dev machine!

Comment: I've created a test db just so i could close this off and it seems CURDATE() works! Cheers Richard.

Answer (score 0):

See Bug 69652 -EDITING: Default date could not be set in a date-field of a form:

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69652

Should be able to enter desired Default Date in the properties of the field, but the field remains blank when one exits the properties dialog.